# Term for discrediting an entire argument based on discrediting a single point of it

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, logic

I'm trying to think of the name of this fallacy, and it's driving me crazy. The typical situation is this: I make a claim, and list several examples supporting this claim. Someone then discredits one of the examples, focuses on that example, and insinuates that the entire argument is invalid based on this.

Example (I do not want this to turn into a political conversation, so please do not focus on the example topic in your response):

- Hypothesis: Political campaigns have emboldened racists to be more open with their hate.
- Evidence: multiple news articles showing examples of political activists acting in hateful ways this week.
- Counterpoint: one of the articles was later shown to be a hoax.
- Counter-conclusion: These articles can't be trusted, so your claim is false.

Your input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We are not logicians here, but you might try [philosophy.se] instead.

Comment: Kind of like  "hasty generalization," https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/tools/lp/Bo/LogicalFallacies/100/Hasty_Generalization, but not quite. You could also try http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/ since this is a word request but also you are looking for a specific logical fallacy which may or may not exist and/or be named.

Comment: I *feel* like there is a term for this out there somewhere. The closest I could come up with is "one bad apple," but it doesn't quite fit. I think this tactic is in the same realm of Internet commenters trying to discredit another commenter based on a grammar error (or misspelling, typo, etc.) in their post.

Comment: Sounds a bit like [fallacy fallacy](https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/the-fallacy-fallacy).

Comment: Thank you all for the input. Throat, sorry I saw similar questions in this forum, but I will definitely try those others, as they appear more suitable. Thank you all for your responses.

Comment: One term to consider is [**association fallacy**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_fallacy), which may involve asserting that because one source of a conclusion is demonstrably false, all sources of the same conclusion must be false, too.

Comment: Demonstrating someone's selected pool of anecdotes includes a lie *is* a legitimate cause to doubt the legitimacy of selection process for the pool. That's not a fallacy, it's just dismissive.

Comment: @SvenYargs - this seems to be more simply [Affirming a Disjunct](http://www.fallacyfiles.org/afonedis.html), in which the OP is saying "P or Q or R" is true, where any of P,Q,R being true makes the entire assertion true.  The fallacy is when someone finds Q to be false, and claims, fallaciously, that the entire assertion is false because of ~Q.

Comment: @stevesliva: I think you're right—and expressing the fallacy in terms of symbolic logic (as you do) is better than treating it as some sort of metaphorical "fruit of the poisoned tree" problem.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the [Fallacy fallacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy_fallacy).  That's when people mistakenly decide a conclusion is false because the argument presented for it is false.

Answer (score 1):

Although "fallacy fallacy" covers the general form of what OP describes, I'd say this is more precisely *cherry picking* perhaps combined with *hasty generalization* as applied to the exact form of the argument being targeted.

Answer (score 0):

I think the word "bias" has a definite role in what you are describing. I looked up some stuff relating to this and the term Negativity Bias might fit? It has to do with the *one bad apple* phrase pyobum mentioned. But here is a link for [negativity bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negativity_bias) and here is a link for [single source bias](https://johngarger.com/articles/methodology/a-definition-of-single-source-bias-in-social-science-research).

Answer (score -1):

I know this isn't as formal as a "fallacy", but I would just call it ignorant, or something like that. it seems just to be bad practice to ignore something completely because of a single mistake.